# play video with the help of font awesome icon in customised screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<body>
<img src="1.jpg" height="300px" width="240px">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjDjIWPwcPU&t=2s"><i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i> </a>
</body>

body{
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
height: auto;
    background-image: url("black.jpg");
}
```

i have written this code the background filled with image(black.jpg) and on that background image.  I have an another image name 1.jpg. i want to play a you tube video  when click on the font awesome video icon in customised window 900*506px in same window.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/h7v0e1ku/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of what exactly you want to do but you should find basics of what you need it this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruc3uaef/15/) I did quickly.

Your code is just a link to the video you wan't to play it will not play it on your current page. So I changed it for :

```
<a id="PlayButton" href="#"><i class="far fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i> </a>
```

So I added an iframe on your code that contain the video and I did hide it on page load.

```
<iframe id="blackpanter" style="display:none;" width="900" height="506" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xjDjIWPwcPU?rel=0" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I added a jquery code do show and play the video when you click on the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#PlayButton").click(function(ev){
  $("#blackpanter").css("display","block");
    $("#blackpanter")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
      ev.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

May I suggest you to learn html, javascript and css basics before moving on further on your project.

Comment: I know basics but how to join them it's an issue for me right now so I asked this question

Comment: Not a problem... Did my solution help you ?

Comment: yes it is working fine. If i want to center this frame what should i do ?

Comment: I will need more code in order to help you with that. I guess you want it to be on center of it's parent ? If so try margin: 0 auto; and make sure that it is display: block. Could you also mark your question as Answered and up vote my answer ?